# Show that sequence $a_{n + 1} = 5a^6_n + 3a^3_{n-1} + a^2_{n-2}$ doesn't include sixth power

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The sequence $(a_n)$ is defined with the recursion $a_{n + 1} = 5a^6_n + 3a^3_{n-1} + a^2_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 2$ and the set of initial values $\{a_0, a_1, a_2\} = \{2013, 2014, 2015\}$. (That is, the initial values are these three numbers in any order.)
Show that the sequence contains no sixth power of a natural number.

This problem is from 2014 austrian regional mathematical olympiad for high school students. That means it is relatively easily. 
I tried using $\rm{mod}\ 7$ and using fermat's little theorem but I don't think that's expected from students.

Comment: Maybe you could find an expression for $ a_n $ via recursive equations and then you could use modular arithmetics.

Comment: I can't seem to get it right

Comment: So, mod $7$ worked? Fermat little's theorem is standard in highschool math olympiads.

Comment: No I can't get that to work either, I may be missing some trick or something.

Comment: All $6$th powers of natural numbers are $\equiv 1(\text{mod}9)$. You may use this fact. May be none of $a_n$ will be such.

Comment: Actually, if we calculate $\operatorname{mod}7$, then we get $4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, \cdots$ in at most $15$ steps for every combination of initial values. Also $\operatorname{mod}9$ works: we get into the cycle $4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6$ within $12$ steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$5x^6\equiv\{0,5\}$$
 $$3x^3\equiv\{0,3,4\}$$
 $$x^2\equiv\{0,1,2,4\}$$ in mod $7$

For $k\ge 3$ , if $\,a_{k-1},a_{k-2},a_{k-3}\not\equiv 0 $, then we cannot get $a_k\equiv 0$ because possible congruences from $\{5\}$, $\{3,4\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$ are $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$. And we have $(2013,2014,2015)\equiv (4,5,6)$ none of them not $\equiv 0$ thus none of $a_k\equiv 0$ and we can assume
 $$5a_{n}^6\equiv\{5\}$$
 $$3a_{n-1}^3\equiv\{3,4\}$$
 $$a_{n-2}^2\equiv \{1,2,4\}$$

which gives $a_n\equiv \{2,3,4,5,6\}$, but any $6^{th}$ power of a natural number is congruent to $0$ or $1$, so there is no such number.

Answer (score 0):

Mod $7$ works.  The $6$'th powers mod $7$ are $0$ and $1$.  Mod $7$, we start with
$a_0, a_1, a_2 \equiv 4,5,6$ mod $7$, but $a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ all $\equiv 3 \mod 7$, 
and then all subsequent terms $\equiv 3$ as well.

Comment: $a_3\equiv 5+3(-1)+2\equiv 4\mod 7$